# Multi tenancy ASP.NET core

Tags: authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, multi-tenant

I'm trying to build ASP.NET core api where I have a few group of users. These groups have a common database, but from there they can only see the records assigned to them.

**For example** the user XYZ calling the controller returning the values from the Products table sees only those that were assigned to his group. And the same when he adds a new Product, only the users of his group see it, and other groups do not know about the existence of this Product.

I would like to ask you to explain to me how to do it in ASP.NET core, what libraries I could use, because unfortunately I don't know how to do it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to search for a library or a framework to build this out, you can do the implementation as follows,

- Create a table that reads as `ProductPermissions`
- Make an entry for recordid, groupid, roleid in this table
- After a user is assigned a group, the relevant tables should have the values like `UserDetails`, `UserGroups`, `UserRoles` etc
- When I want to see the list of products that are accessible to me, I make a request to the `GetProducts` API.
- The API gets my userid from the authentication process, roles and group ids
- Now, you have to join the products table and the `ProductPermissions` table with the keys and filter by the groupid that I have been assigned.
- The same logic applies for all the entity operations that I do, any action will be validated against the `ProductPermissions` table.

**Note**

In order to get a generic table than redundant `ProductPermissions`, you can have the table as `EntityPermissions` and then have the entityId (ex: `Product`, `Category` etc) as a column and that will be used a filter during joining so that you have a single table for all entities.